# Monitoring a "Program Close" event on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, event-handling

I'm currently developing an application that requires monitoring when an application opens and closes to pull data from its log file (this sounds dumb but it's the only way).

I'm completely new to Windows programming and wondering if monitoring an application's open/close events is possible? I was having trouble finding the right information online. What resources online would cover this?

Comment: It might be more prudent to just monitor the log file directly. The OS can tell you when the file changes, or when there are changes to any files in a given directory.

Comment: @RobKennedy I really like this solution! Where would I be able to find the OS API (is this right?) to be able to do this?

Comment: Why dont you start the application that needs to be monitored with your monitoring application and whait till it finishes (returns exit code) and then just proceed to open log file. In other words, you can use system call to start the application and whait till system call returns in one thread, while the others do somethong else, like user input processing. Sorry for my english.

Comment: You might try asking Stack Overflow or Google how to detect when a file or directory changes.

Comment: @Radon Yeah, I was wondering how I would be able to monitor the exit code for an application on windows, but I'm not 100% sure how. I know exactly what the application name is, too.

I'm building an application to monitor another that I don't have the source code to or anything.

Comment: @RobKennedy Figured it out! Thanks, man.